# Can AWS Aurora Serverless Clusters be configured via AWS Explorer in DataGrip?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I'm currently having issues setting up the AWS Explorer plugin in DataGrip to recognise the Aurora Serverless Clusters (MySQL). I have set up credentials from IAM in the credentials file, and can access other AWS services (if I select the dropdown "Schemas", for example, I can see the list of schemas in my org) but clicking the RDS dropdown shows "empty", and doesn't even show the list of database engines. I have tried connecting with secrets manager and using the correct secret for the DB cluster but no luck. When I try and add the database cluster as a data source, it just hangs on "Introspecting" and then the endpoint for that cluster.

I found this issue on the aws-toolkit for jetbrains github https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/2124

which mentions that it could be a driver problem. I have tried changing to the mySQL driver, and that hasn't seemed to fix it. DataGrip also seems to heavily encourage using the recommended Aurora MySQL driver.

Is this a bug with DataGrip, or AWS Explorer, or am I missing something obvious? Do I need to enable SSL CAs to get AWS Explorer the correct permissions?

Thanks!

EDIT: I have gone through the prerequisites listed on the AWS docs:

I have installed the AWS CLI and AWS SAM CLI

I have installed Docker (but I haven't set up any containers - I think this is
only needed if I'm running localhost?)

I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurora serverless **can't be accessed from the internet**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html):

> You must create your Aurora Serverless DB cluster in an Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC). Aurora Serverless DB clusters are **accessible only from an Amazon VPC and can't use a public IP address**.

Thus, you need to setup VPN or some proxy (e.g. ssh tunnel through a bastion host) to be able to connect to Aurora serverless from outside of AWS.